# Install VLC automatically install without hitting next

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will install VLC from the server. What happens when I run the script is every computer name in my text file will start the install process where you will then hit "next next next" (basically).

I was curious of how I can write these scripts for any software to just install and not prompt for all of those "next" and just install on its own. Is this possible to do?

```
# Run As Administrator

Function Get-FileName{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [String]$Filter = "|*.*",
    [String]$InitialDirectory = "C:\")

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = $Filter
    [void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$file = Get-FileName -InitialDirectory $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Filter "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
ForEach ($item in (Get-Content $file)) {
    $sitem = $item.Split("|")
    $computer = $sitem[0].Trim()
    $user = $sitem[1].Trim()

    $filepath = Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\"
    If ($filepath -eq $false) {
    Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service

    Copy-Item -Path "\\server\Unsupported Software\VLC MediaPlayer" -Destination "\\$computer\c$\windows\temp\" -Container -Recurse -Force

    $InstallString = '"C:\windows\temp\VLC MediaPlayer\vlc-2.2.1-win32.exe"'
    ([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)

    "$computer" + "-" + "$(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Unsupported Software\VLC MediaPlayer\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append

    } Else {
        "$computer" + "_Already_Had_Software_" + "$(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Unsupported Software\VLC MediaPlayer\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Installing_VLC/), you can just use the command line switch to install VLC like:

```
vlc-2.0.1-win32.exe /L=1033 /S
```

Where `/S` probably is a switch for *silent* installation.

Comment: so is every application different then? Or does this cover most applications?

Comment: Also do you know where in my script I would add this?

Comment: Of course this can be differ for each application but most applications provide such silent installations. However, you have to check the command line installation syntax for each application. You probably have to add it on your `$InstallString` variable

Comment: does it go in this line? `$InstallString = '"C:\windows\temp\VLC MediaPlayer\vlc-2.2.1-win32.exe"'`

Comment: probably yes. There are many ways in PowerShell to launch an application, I never used WMICLASS.